# Quill editor angular BlotFormatter for image resize not working

Tags: angular, quill, angular12, ngx-quill

I am using quill editor for angular and trying to resize image with **quill-blot-formatter**. It loads and shows resizable points on image corners as shown in below image, but resize of image is not working.

Image loaded with resize points at corners

[image: 1]

**Component code**

```
import Quill from 'quill'
import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter';
Quill.register('modules/blotFormatter', BlotFormatter);
```

**Packages.json**

```
"@angular/cli": "12.0.2"
"ngx-quill": "^14.3.0"
"quill": "^1.3.7"
"quill-blot-formatter": "^1.0.5"
```

**angular.json**

```
"scripts": [                            
"./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js",                            
"./node_modules/quill-blot-formatter/dist/quill-blot-formatter.min.js"]
```

Comment: Did you got any solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: No it didn't worked, i ended-up by changing the editor to summernote editor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the property

```
blotFormatter: { },
```

With this you will already have the function of changing the size of the image, I add an image with the detail of the function

[image]

Comment: Hi @joshue, i tried using your suggestion but still no luck

Comment: I also tried but not working for me.